# RCurl issue when installing SCnorm

Tags: r, scrnaseq, rcurl

I am working on the `Rivanna` cluster that is of `SLURM`-type. Because of that I do not have write permissions and need to install the newest `R` version myself locally, and use it. For it to be successfully built from source, I needed to also build from source `libcurl4-openssl-dev`, so I downloaded `tar.gz` file from here:

https://packages.debian.org/ru/jessie/libcurl4-openssl-dev

and did:

```
mkdir build 
./configure --prefix=/scratch/nv4e/curl/build
make
make install
```

Then, in the same way I built from source `R` `3.5.1`, the latest current version. It was compiled without any errors, but with some warnings. Then, I submitted the `R` script that uses `SCnorm` package:

https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/SCnorm.html

Inside of the script I am having:

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("SCnorm")
biocLite("SingleCellExperiment")
library(SCnorm)
library(SingleCellExperiment)
```

Of course, I am submitting it through `.slurm` file where I have the main command:

```
Rscript --vanilla scnorm.R
```

It fails, apparently because `SCnorm` requires `RCurl`, but it can not get one, even though in the log file it is trying to access it correctly:

[image]

The `libcurl` library was built from source in the `/scratch/nv4e/curl/build` folder. The only suspicion that I have here is that maybe its version is wrong and `SCnorm` needs another `libcurl` version? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

> Update

I tried reinstalling `libcurl` library from the official website, using the latest version:

https://curl.haxx.se/

But it did not fix the issue. I have also tried using `libcurl` from `Anaconda` but it gave the same error. So, neither `7.61.0` (latest), nor `7.29.0` (`Anaconda`), nor `7.38.0` (`Debian` link) are working.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug affecting the curl compile, it's been reported [here](https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/846) and also [here](https://github.com/curl/curl/pull/1404), I suggest trying to compile from the newer release of the libcurl source rather than the `.deb` you linked.

Comment: I tried reinstalling `libcurl` from here: https://curl.haxx.se/, and it did not help. I see that the `R` is using the newly reinstalled version, and giving the same error.

Comment: Are you sure it's not hitting the old system version at compile time?

Comment: Yes, sure. Cluster support fixed it. The issue was related to gcc version, but I am not completely sure what they did.

Comment: Glad it got fixed, although if you find out exactly it would be good to post and answer since this will help others with the same issue.